# Do JSR-303 type java field validations always/implicitly run before field ones?

Tags: java, validation, object, field, bean-validation

If I am using the `javax.validation.Validator` to validate an object annotated with constraints, will it always evaluate the field level constraints before the object?

For example if I have:

```
@DummyClassValidation
public static class DummyClassToValidate {

    private Integer myNum;

    @Min(value = 50)
    @Max(value = 100)
    public Integer getMyNum() {
        return myNum;
    }

    public void setMyNum(Integer myNum) {
        this.myNum = myNum;
    }
}
```

And I validate it, is it guaranteed that the `@DummyClassValidation` will be evaluated only after `@Min` and `@Max`?  I know I can do so with Groupings but I rather not if I don't have to (i.e. Field validations are implicitly grouped to validate before object validations).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the specification](http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr303/index.html), section 3.5:

> For a given group to validate, the validation routine applied on a
>   given bean instance is expected to execute the following constraint
>   validations in no particular order:
>
> - for all reachable fields,
>     execute all field level validations (including the ones expressed on
>     superclasses) matching the targeted group unless the given validation
>     constraint has already been processed during this validation routine
>     for a given navigation path (see Section 3.5.1) as part of a previous
>     group match.
> - for all reachable getters, execute all getter level
>     validations (including the ones expressed on interfaces and
>     superclasses) matching the targeted group unless the given validation
>     constraint has already been processed during this validation routine
>     for a given navigation path (see Section 3.5.1) as part of a previous
>     group match.
> - execute all class level validations (including the ones
>     expressed on interfaces and superclasses) matching the targeted group
>     unless the given validation constraint has already been processed
>     during this validation routine for a given navigation path (see
>     Section 3.5.1) as part of a previous group match.
> - for all reachable
>     and cascadable associations, execute all cascading validations (see
>     Section 3.5.1) including the ones expressed on interfaces and
>     superclasses (see Section 3.4.5)

In short, you can't rely on that unless you want to find an implementation that guarantees it and stick with that.

Comment: Maybe interesting to note, that some implementations "disregard" this specification: [JSF 2 doesn't execute class-level validations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9212777/1803692)